# What's the difference between updateMany() and bulkWrite() in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

AFAIK, both operations can update multiple documents. If so, what is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just quoting the [API docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html) here

[bulkWrite](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.bulkWrite)

> Sends multiple insertOne, updateOne, updateMany, replaceOne,
>   deleteOne, and/or deleteMany operations to the MongoDB server **in one
>   command**. This is faster than sending multiple independent operations
>   (like) if you use create()) because with bulkWrite() there is only one
>   round trip to MongoDB.
>
> Mongoose will perform casting on all operations you provide.
>
> This function does not trigger any middleware, not save() nor
>   update(). If you need to trigger save() middleware for every document
>   use create() instead.

[updateMany](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.updateMany)

> Same as update(), except MongoDB **will update all documents that match
>   filter** (as opposed to just the first one) regardless of the value of
>   the multi option.
>
> Note updateMany will not fire update middleware. Use pre('updateMany')
>   and post('updateMany') instead.

(emphasis mine)

To see examples of use take a look at the ones provided in the function's respective documentation.

Comment: Thanks! It's still not clear whether updateMany also requires a single round-trip to the server or not.

Comment: @omer UpdateMany will do the job in a single round trip only. In the `BulkWrite`, you can do additional CRUD operations simultaneously whereas, in the `UpdateMany`, you will be able to do update operations only.